# nginx access/deny to specific path

Tags: nginx-location

I have an nginx vhost where I want to :

- Allow access to http://host.domain/admin/web/index.php/rules_engine
- Deny access to http://host.domain/admin/web/index.php
- Same for index_dev.php

This is want I have currently

```
location ^~ /admin/web/index[_dev]*.php/rules_engine {
  allow all;
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^ /admin/web/index.php$is_args$args last;
  }
}

location /admin/web/index[_dev]*.php {
  deny all;
}
```

but it does not deny access to /admin/web/index.php

Can anyone highlight me where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the following config did the trick:

```
  location ^~ /admin/web/index[_dev]*\.php/rules_engine {
    allow all;
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^ /admin/web/index.php$is_args$args last;
    }
  }

  location ~ /admin/web/index[_dev]*\.php(/$|$) {
    deny all;
  }
```